# Casting ActiveRecord data types to SQL Server columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, redmine

I am trying to install Redmine on Windows Server with MS SQL Server database.
Getting error

```
can't cast ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServer::Type::Char::Data to varchar
```

in method

```
  # Generates a new session token and returns its value
  def generate_session_token
    token = Token.create!(:user_id => id, :action => 'session')
    token.value
  end
```

Column `action` is `VARCHAR(30)`.
Migrations ran successfully. Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @F0rc0sigan Yes, by changing active record version and ruby version.
Ruby was downgraded to 2.1. I suppose this problem comes from tiny tds package.